# Bettermap is not working on Banana dashboard

Tags: solr, banana

we are ingesting our collection that has a latlon field so called posicion with the following schema, i.e:

45.17614,-93.87341

When we are trying to visualize on Banana, it seems that is loading properly on the table panel:

[image: banana]

It seems that is able to 'understand' that is a proper field as it finds its 0_coordinate and 1_coordinate. However, bettermap doesn't seem to print it.

Any idea?

Comment: Which version/branch are you using? Note: make sure you check "Auto Fit Bounds" option in Bettermap panel options.

Comment: Hi @aadel, we have tried among the diferent options but seems no one loads data

Comment: Hi @ivan, what is the value of bettermap panel query and custom queries? Note #2: make sure to leave Starting long/lat and Ending long/lat blank while "Auto Fit Bounds" is checked and put "posicion" in "Coordinate Field".

Comment: Please check this answer. This is how I solved my bettermap panel issue. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54938833/3300911