# How to visualize data on bettermap in Banana Solr Dashboard?

Tags: solr, banana

I am trying to visualize a set of indexed data through Banana and it's bettermap panel.

Below is my indexed data for storing the lat long information:

```
{
        "user_lang":"en",
        "user_screenname":"Kashyep2",
        "latlonggis_0_coordinate":25.25,
        "latlonggis_1_coordinate":86.98,
        "latlonggis":"25.25,86.98",
        "longlatgis_0_coordinate":86.98,
        "longlatgis_1_coordinate":25.25,
        "longlatgis":"86.98,25.25",
        "timestamp":"2019-02-09T08:09:09.280Z",
        "_version_":1624977964309413888}
  }
```

I do not get any thing on the bettermap panel.

My question is whether the data format shown above to represent the lat long information is correct?

Comment: Are you using Lucidworks in this stack or strictly Solr?

Comment: https://doc.lucidworks.com/lucidworks-hdpsearch/2.5/Guide-Banana.html

Comment: that's a 2 year old release which is no longer supported

Comment: There are no further releases to it anyway and it seems to be the latest though old. Except banana there is no other non time series dashboard tool for Solr search engine. The solution mentioned as an answer is the correct solution. Feel free though to let me know of any other non time series dashboard tool for Solr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the banana sourcecode inside panels/bettermap/module.js the following changes had to be made.

```
//var sorting = '&sort=' + filterSrv.getTimeField() + ' desc'; // Only get the latest data, sorted by time field.

// Removed the sorting field from the final query
$scope.panel.queries.query = querySrv.getORquery() + wt_json + rows_limit + fq;
```

The filterSrv.getTimeField() is undefined for the query and hence the locations could not be displayed on the map.